# How to call `graphql` query from within a "onPointClicked" callback

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql

I am attempting to call a `graphql` query when a user clicks on a data point in a `three.js` render. I am getting an error specifying that

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

This makes sense due to the way that I am currently calling it, but I cannot see how else to do it.

What I am looking to do is to "load" the query when a point has been clicked, passing in the ID of the clicked point (hardcoded to 0 here) and then use `usePreloadedQuery` to return the data.

How can you call `usePreloadedQuery` outside of the `onPointClicked` callback?

```js
...

// Imports include:
import {
  graphql,
  useQueryLoader,
  usePreloadedQuery,
} from "react-relay";
import {
  PointCloudPointsNearestNeighbourQuery as NearestNeighbourQueryType
} from "./__generated__/PointCloudPointsNearestNeighbourQuery.graphql";
...

// My graphql query
const PointCloudPointsNearestNeighbourQuery = graphql`
  query PointCloudPointsNearestNeighbourQuery(
    $id: GlobalID!, 
    $idx: Int!
  ) {
    embedding: node(id: $id) {
      ... on EmbeddingDimension {
        NeighbourPoints(idx: $idx) {
          embeddingNeighbours
          projectionNeighbours
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;


export function PointCloudPoints(.....) {
    ...
    const [queryReference, loadQuery] = useQueryLoader<NearestNeighbourQueryType>(PointCloudPointsNearestNeighbourQuery);

    ...
    const onPointClicked = useCallback(
      (point: PointBaseProps) => {
        loadQuery(
          {
            id: embeddingDimensionId,
            idx: 0 // Hardcoded for now
          },
          {
            fetchPolicy: "network-only",
          }
        );

        startTransition(() => {
      
          if (queryReference != null) {
            // ERROR BEING GENERATED FROM HERE
            const data = usePreloadedQuery<NearestNeighbourQueryType>(
              PointCloudPointsNearestNeighbourQuery,
              queryReference
            );

            const neighbourData = useMemo(
              () =>
                data.embedding?.NeighbourPoints?.embeddingNeighbours ?? [],
              [data]
            );

            const stringSet: Set<string> = new Set(neighbourData.map((num) => num.toString()));

            setNeighbourIds(stringSet);

        } 

      });
    },
    [setSelectedEventIds, setNeighbourIds, queryReference]
  );
}
...
```